# Unique values of Dictionary comprehension, return dictionary instread of string

Tags: python, dictionary, set, dictionary-comprehension

this is my data:

```
data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'The Musical Hop', 'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA'},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'The Dueling Pianos Bar', 'city': 'New York', 'state': 'NY'},
{'id': 3, 'name': 'Park Square Live Music & Coffee', 'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA'}]
```

I want to find out the unique values (thats why I use a set) of "city" and return them like this:

```
cities = set([x.get("city") for x in data])
cities ´

{'New York', 'San Francisco'}
```

However, I also want to return the corresponding state, like this:

```
[{"city": "New York", "state": "NY"}, {"city":  "San Francisco", "state": "CA"}]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How would you handle the situation if there are 2 cities in different states with the same name?

Comment: Probably ignore it for the sake of my "fun" project right now, but yes, this should be addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dict-comprehension for the task:

```
out = list({x['city']:{'city':x['city'], 'state':x['state']} for x in data}.values())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'city': 'San Francisco', 'state': 'CA'}, {'city': 'New York', 'state': 'NY'}]
```

Comment: awesome! constructing the values and de-duping all in one dict comprehension

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dict-comprehension to create a city->state mapping, then iterate it to create the list you want:

```py
city_to_state = {x["city"]: x["state"] for x in data}
result = [{"city":k, "state":v} for k,v in city_to_state.items()]
```